# python plot multiple histogram same time with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I created a different histogram plot using data from a file. Now I wanted to combine these plot into a single histogram. Below is the code to generate a different histogram.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections
import numpy as np

df  = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/rajive/Desktop/Final_code/MSCN1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/rajive/Desktop/Final_code/MSCN2.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/rajive/Desktop/Final_code/MSCN3.xlsx')
df3 = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/rajive/Desktop/Final_code/MSCN4.xlsx')

def calculate_pair_product_coefficients () :
    return collections.OrderedDict ({
        'mscn1' : df,
        'mscn2' : df1,
        'mscn3' : df2,
        'mscn4' : df3,
#       'mscn1' : mscn_coefficients, 
        })

def plot_histogram (x, label) :
    n, bins = np.histogram (x.ravel (), bins = 100)
    n = n / np.max (n)

plt.plot (bins [:-1], n, color = 'green', label = label, marker = 'o')

coefficients = calculate_pair_product_coefficients ()
plt.rcParams ["figure.figsize"] = 12, 11

for name, coeff in coefficients.items () :
    plot_histogram (coeff.values.ravel (), name)
    plt.axis ([-2, 2, 0, 1.05])
    plt.legend ()
    plt.show ()
```

Comment: So to clarify, do you want 4 subplots with a histogram in each or all the data combined into 1 singular histogram to create 1 plot?

Comment: @BenT I am interested in plotting all the data into 1 singular histogram.